# Use App.Config of DLL at an Office Addin written with IDTExtensibility2 instead od VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-office, app-config, office-addins

we have built an Office Addin implementing the IDTExtensibility2 Interface (and the IRibbon... and Taskpane) the Addin is using a Webservice whos binding should be configured via the App.config of the Addin.dll... we now found out that the binding has either be created manually by configuring everything directly in C# or the config settings have to be written in the targetApp.exe.Config - which is in our case Windword.exe.config.
This is not a clean solution for deploying - so is there any way (Except switching to VSTO and  fool arround with Ribbon and Taskpane at this end?) reading the config from the dll.config file?
We do not have a manifest and or vsto file created (because our addin is not based on the VSTO)
Using a configurationmanager and read everything manually by code and instantiate the binding is a bit cruel... any ideas?! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own app domain and configure it so that it automatically uses the config file, as you would expect under other app.config scenarios. Use [`AppDomain.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aehss7y0.aspx) with an [`AppDomainSetup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.aspx) with the [`ConfigurationFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx) property set to the path of your app.config.

Comment: OK - got you so far, but how can I get a new BasicHTTPBinding derived from this AppDomain Context?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "get" a new BasicHTTPBinding. Are you trying to use app.config to configure and automatically set up your WCF stuff, or do you want to configure them in app.config and then programmatically work with them? In the simplest of cases, you configure your settings in app.config and that configuration is used automatically. To do that, I think you'll need to create your own AppDomain as in my answer. But the flip side is that cross-domain programming has its own complexities, so you'll have to weigh these two and figure out which is better for you.

Comment: Hi, we are accessing a webservice from within the Addin - for its binding we need an app.config - otherwise we have to put it into the winword.exe.config (which seems to be quite ugly) the other way - we are using by now (also ugly) is to create a new basichttpbinding object and set all its values and then derive the soapclient stuff from this

Comment: and what we want to achief is, that the basicHTTPBindig ob derives its settings from the app.config we specified in the appdomain...

Comment: Hi thx - it seems that we have to switch our webservice from SOAP to WCF then using a configurationmanager where we can load any config file and then get a channel factory... that should work for us... the AppDomain does not help since we can not run our component in a different Daomain - that would imply massive changes in the design... thx